# Want to create unique and autofill the value of the model whenever user fill the form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, uuid

here is my model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
coinid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True, null=True)
digit = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique = True, null=True)
ctp = models.FloatField(max_length=100, null=True)
transection_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

when the user fills the form which includes = coinid and ctp.
I want Django to automatically fill Digit(unique) and user(logged in) fields for me when updated to the products table.
here is my form.py

```
class CreateProduct(ModelForm):


class Meta:
    model = Product

    fields = ['user','coinid', 'ctp']
    exclude = ['user']
```

views.py

```
def createProduct(request):

user_id = request.user.customer
form = CreateProduct(instance=user_id)

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = CreateProduct(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       
        form.save()

        
        return redirect('/products/')

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'accounts/newcoin.html', context)
```

Also, I want to validate the product's ctp value whenever a user types in the unique digit to another form.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the save method on the Product model to achieve what you want

example: models.py

```
import uuid

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, 
           blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coinid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True, null=True)
    digit = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique = True, null=True)
    ctp = models.FloatField(max_length=100, null=True)
    transection_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *awags, **kwargs):
        # if coinid and ctp is not none
        # save a uuid in the digit field
        if self.coinid and self.ctp:
            self.digit = str(uuid.uuid4())
        # Your code to change the user model here
        # exmaple to change user name
        user = User.objects.get(id = self.user.id)
        user.username = "Stackoverflow user"
        user.save()
        super().save(*awags, **kwargs)
```

You can check the Django docs for reference to [override Save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method

For creating unique IDs you can use the python uuid module

```
import uuid
unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

You can also use `uuid.uuid1()` however the docs recommends uuid4 for a random unique string

You can check the docs for uuid [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)

Comment: thank you for your response, can you tell me how this will be applied in views?

Comment: and how can I create a unique autogenerated digit

Comment: Hi @srfreak, I have updated my answer, check if it helps, thanks

Comment: you don't have to change the views since the form will handle the creating of the object and save it when you call form.save(), the logic should be handled in the overrode save method of the Product model